# Создание submenu со своим меню в Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, menu

Как сделать (если возможно) подменю с еще одним подменю?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. мне нужно чтобы при наведении мышкой на подменю 
(`"*Open*", "*Save*", "*Save as*", "*Exit*"`) 
выпадало меню:
(`"*Tk1*", "*Tk2*", "*Tk3*", "*Tk4*"`) 
вправо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пожалуйста предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему. Как вариант, это может выглядеть так:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("Добавляем подменю")

        menubar = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)

        submenu = Menu(fileMenu)
        submenu.add_command(label="Tk1")
        submenu.add_command(label="Tk2")
        submenu.add_command(label="Tk3")
        submenu.add_command(label="Tk4")
        fileMenu.add_cascade(label='Open', menu=submenu, underline=0)
        fileMenu.add_cascade(label='Save', menu=submenu, underline=0)

        fileMenu.add_separator()

        fileMenu.add_command(label="Выход", underline=0, command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Файл", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)

    def onExit(self):
        self.quit()


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = Example()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня почему-то код не работает (PyCharm). Наверно разберусь

Comment: @AlexSam что значит не работает? А если запустить в консоли/CMD/терминале - `python main.py`

Comment: @S.Nick возможно потому что вызова функции main() нет)

Comment: @insolor спасибо